# Get Two Specific Word Using Regex and Save it to HashMap

Tags: java, regex, string

I need a help,
I have a String like

```
LOCALHOST = https://192.168.56.1
```

I want to get the "LOCALHOST" and the IP address then save it to HashMap

This is my code so far, I didnt  know how to use regex, please help
The output that I want is in HashMap {LOCALHOST=192.168.56.1}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String line = "LOCALHOST = https://192.168.56.1";
        //this should be a hash map
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

        //didnt know how to get two string
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^ =]+)").matcher(line);       
        while (m.find()) {
            urls.add(m.group());      
        }

        System.out.println(urls);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: What is the issue? What output did you got when running that code?

Comment: the output is: LOCALHOST, https://192.168.56.1
I didn't know hot to get that localhost and IP
and save it to hashmap as key and object

Comment: With this regexp, you should get `"LOCALHOST"` and `"https://192.168.56.1"`. What exactly is your issue? The insertion in a HashMap? Or do you want a regexp to get the IP address without the http:// ?

Comment: Do you want a map or a list? You mention hashmap in the title SND the code, but you create a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try something like the following:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.+) = https:\\/\\/(\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})$");
m.matcher(line);
final Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String();       
if (m.matches())
{
   final String lh = m.group(1);
   final String ip = m.group(2);
   map.add(lh,ip);
}
```

Learn to use a good interactive Regular Expression editor like the one at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/eG7sV7)

```
/^(.+) = https:\/\/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})$/m
^ Start of line
1st Capturing group (.+) 
. 1 to infinite times [greedy] Any character (except newline)
 = https:\/\/ Literal  = https://
2nd Capturing group (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) 
\d 1 to 3 times [greedy] Digit [0-9]
\. Literal .
\d 1 to 3 times [greedy] Digit [0-9]
\. Literal .
\d 1 to 3 times [greedy] Digit [0-9]
\. Literal .
\d 1 to 3 times [greedy] Digit [0-9]
$ End of line
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as per the title:

```
String line = "LOCALHOST = https://192.168.56.1";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] parts = line.split(" *= *");
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

The regex splits on equals sign and consumes any spaces around it too so you don't have to trim to parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "LOCALHOST = https://192.168.56.1";

String []s =line.split("=");
map.put(s[0].trim(), s[1].trim());
```

Answer (score -2):

This is very simple and does not require 'matcher/pattern' regex. Try This:

```
HashMap<String, String> x = new HashMap<String, String>();

String line = "LOCALHOST = https://192.168.56.1";

String[] items = line.split("=");

x.add(items[0], items[1]);
```

Comment: I meant it doesn't use 'matcher/pattern' regex.